# Regular expression match optional item unless optional item contains a certain string?

Tags: javascript, regex

**[The Problem]**

I have a URL scheme I'm trying to create a regex for. I have one part of the scheme to be optional, but if a certain string (let's say the string is `Apple`) is matched anywhere in the string, it should fail.

**[Examples]**

Strings that should **succeed**:
`http://example.com/en/Parent`
`http://example.com/en/Parent/`
`http://example.com/en/Parent/ArbitraryWord`
`http://example.com/en/Parent/ArbitraryWord/anythingelse`

Strings that should **fail**:
`http://example.com/en/Parent/Apple`
`http://example.com/en/Parent/Apple/anythingelse`

**[What I've Tried]**

I started out with `/\/Parent\/(?!Apple)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gi`, but that didn't match `http://example.com/en/Parent` because the regex expects a trailing slash and another string. Then I tried `/\/Parent(\/)?(?!Apple)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/gi`, which does match the `/Parent/` URL, but also does not fail when `Apple` is present.

**[jsFiddle]**

http://jsfiddle.net/Luf9zsw4/1/

Comment: I suggest using http://www.regexr.com/ to test your expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
/\/Parent(?:\/((?!Apple).*))?$/img
```

Comment: @Jake Add the `$` assert in the pattern with `m` modifier. It'll work -> http://jsfiddle.net/4pub1cqa/1/